# how to get the browser's size in node.js?

Tags: node.js

how would I get the browser size in node.js?
I want to send it to a jade template so it can place a unknown amount of divs on the page spaced equally.
if getting the users screen size is not the best way of doing it please let me know a different solution (its probably not the best way. but the only other thing i could think of is a script `for each div this.width = window.width/number of divs` and that also seems bad).

thanks,
Porad

Comment: You might want to become familiar with Responsive Web Design http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Answer (score 6, accepted):

node.js operates on the server side.  From there it cannot see the client-size.

Your best bet is going to be to determine this via javascript on the client-side, such that any request, subsequent to the first, will be able to request the correct size.

This won't work if the client has javascript disabled, and for the initial load, so you're going to want to send a sensible default.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/device, if all you need is maybe just checking what device user is using therefore, no need to check screen resolution at all.

Otherwise, you may just have to make a HTTP call to send that resolution to server side.

```
var device = require('device');
var mydevice = device('put here user-agent string');

if(mydevice.is('phone'))
    // do something... 
else
    // do another thing...
```

Comment: Damn.... it f****** worked! Nice one! This is really useful to me because I am doing SSR with Next.js and it needs to apply styles for mobile and desktop using window, which it doesn't have on initial render, so there would be a flash of wrong styles. This way I can assume the window.innerWidth etc. because of device type: phone / desktop etc. :)